# Data parallelism - Testng

Tags: java, testng

I am creating 20 test data and storing it in a hashmap for the test execution.

And I'm running the testng suite with 2 parallel threads.

Test method randomly picks the data from the hashmap and executing it but sometimes if already used data being piced and exected in another test method the test cases got failed.

So I need a solution if the hashmap data is already picked next thread shouldn't picked it and move to next data in the hashmap.

Please provide your suggestion.

Comment: That depends on how you implemented that and how and why the test fails. AFAIU you have a single source of data for different tests.

Comment: @nmkp It would be good if you post some part of the code as well as it is not clear why the same data fails only when it is repicked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use data provider instead of HashMap, this works perfectly in parallel threads

```
@DataProvider(name = "moving-ecs")
public Object[][] moving_ecs(){
    return new Object[][] {{"1"},{"2"},{"73"},{"74"},{"13"},{"14"},{"3"}};
}


@Test( dataProvider = "moving-ecs")
```

Still if you need hashmap,

you need to build another hashmap with name completedKey. every time it is taken, add it to this completedKey hashmap and before doing you need to verify that key present in this completedKey hashmap.